# Is it best to use a single table for current and archived records, or one for archived and one for current

Tags: mysql, spring, postgresql, jpa

One of the applications I work with is a Spring JPA clinical records application.  It has two tables to track admissions; "Visits" and "Admissions".  Visits is a huge table holding visit records for 100,000's of patients.  Admissions is an "active" table holding only records for currently admitted patients.  As the patients are discharged they are deleted from the Admissions table.  The thinking here was that users are mostly interest in current admissions so we need current admission searches to be fast - hence the smaller table.  However, it does add complexity and overhead whereas it would be possible just to have an "admitted" flag on the visits table and the currently admitted queries can search on visits instead thus simplifying the application structure and possibly improving performance.  I understand normal form here and that it is somewhat broken by duplicating data across two tables.  I am just interested to know if a single table would be a preferred approach or if the current design would be considered appropriate?  My primary concern is performance and in testing there is not a significant difference (from a user perspective).  I don't believe there is any recognized "pattern" for this problem - but there may be?

Comment: [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: I have just been hit by a bolt of lightening - @RangePartitioning - thank you!

Comment: [Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

Comment: Are you sure that visits is huge? A hundred visits for a million patients would be 100 million rows. This is large, but not unmanageably so. (I'm not quite convinced that partitioning will help much here, but I may be mistaken)

Comment: From what I am reading partitioning is at least a more "systematic" approach - better than having two tables with all the overheads of maintaining the records in both.

Comment: Definately one table marked with the time the patient was discharged. Create a view of the currently active patients. This has the advantage that you can see how the activity changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

What does a row represent?  Presumably not a 'person',  but rather some action (visit, admission, discharge, etc)?

The number of visits will be several times the number of admissions?

Are the admissions limited to "those currently occupying a bed"?  Or does it include previously discharged patients?

To help with the above questions, think about what *queries* need to be performed.  And what bits of data are needed in those queries.

Textbooks will insist on one "proper" form of laying out the database.  I lean toward pragmaticism.  Here are some factors that would push me toward separate tables:

- The number rows in, say, `visits` is a lot bigger than the number of rows in `admissions`.
- There are a non-trivial number of columns that do not show up in both tables.
- Many queries only need to look at one table, not the other.  (`UNION ALL` can be used when you need data from both.)
- The "common" data can be normalized out of both.  (Example:  non-hospital info about a `person`'.  Caution:  `address`, etc can change over time.)
- Different indexes are needed to optimize the different queries.
- Perhaps an "admission" is a superset of a "visit"?  That is, there might be one row in each table for a single event.  (cf `JOIN` or perhaps `LEFT JOIN`.)

There is no "right" answer.  There may not even be a clear winner in a contest.  Implement it one way, *but with the sincere intent of revisiting the question in a few months*.

You mentioned that a smaller table is faster -- That depends.  Properly indexed, table size has only a small impact on speed.  When there is no viable index is when size matters.  So...  Think through the `SELECTs` *now*, even before you design the tables.  Sure it is twice the work, but it is useful -- for learning, for practice, *and* for helping make the decision.